# How to solve for the matrix in a set of equations involving the matrix exponential?

Tags: exponentiation, matrices, inverse-problems

I was wondering how to solve the following problem (in a least-squares sense):

$$
\mathbf{y}_1 = e^{Ax_1} \mathbf{y}_0 \\
\mathbf{y}_2 = e^{Ax_2} \mathbf{y}_0 \\
\vdots\\
\mathbf{y}_n = e^{Ax_n} \mathbf{y}_0 
$$

with vectors $\mathbf{y}_i$ and scalars $x_i$ for $i=0,1,...,n$ all known. In other words; the unknown in this set of equations is the matrix $A$ in the exponential.

Comment: What dimension is $A$?